# Complex reductive search - changing from keyup to button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

After having a few small wins with JS (still very much a learner) I have now inherited a task which is to change a reductive search of sorts.

Users now want to have the search work from a submit button, instead of a keyup after 3rd character.

I have had a look through the large JS file, and located the search function which contains the keyup function.

```
  F.initSearch = function(opts){
    if(!opts || !opts.ele){
      return;
    }
  
    if(!opts.start_length){
      this.opts.search.start_length = 2
    }
  
    this.$search_ele = $(this.opts.search.ele);
  
    if(this.$search_ele.length){
      this.has_search = true;
      this.searchFn = this.buildSearchFn(opts.fields);
      this.bindEvent(opts.ele, 'keyup');
    }
  };
```

However, I am having difficulty with changing over from keyup to button click. The JS is way above my current skill level.

This is what I have done:

I have updated the form to include the button

```
   <form>
       <div class="searchBox">
         <input type="text" id="search" class="search__text-input" placeholder="Search"/>
       </div>
      
       <div class="formBox">
           <button id="searchbtn">Search</button>
       </div>     
   </form>
```

I have tried to update the script with some jquery which follows the same pattern

```
$( "#searchbtn" ).this.bindEvent(opts.ele, 'click');
```

Lastly, I have attempted to then update the existing - which is now leaving me somewhat defeated:

```
F.initSearch = function(opts) {
    if(!opts || !opts.ele) {
        return;
    }
    if(!opts.start_length) {
        this.opts.search.start_length = 2
    }
    this.$search_ele = $(this.opts.search.ele);
    if(this.$search_ele.length) {
        this.has_search = true;
        this.searchFn = this.buildSearchFn(opts.fields);
        // this.bindEvent(opts.ele, 'keyup');

/* Trying to swap keyup for button click */

        $( "#searchbtn" ).this.bindEvent(opts.ele, 'click');



    }
};
```

How I have structured in the past:

```
<input type='button' value='Submit search' onClick='submitSearch()' />

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function submitSearch() {
       $("#searchId").submit();
    }
</script>
```

Sorry for my long winded question. I am still learning Javascript, and would really appreciate someone who is willing to share some knowledge to put me back on track.

Here is my JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/mcmacca002/bo0y3u7p/2/

Thank you.

Comment: `.this.bindEvent(opts.ele, 'click');` isn't valid jquery. You are effectively asking how to bind a click event...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `$( "#searchbtn" ).this.bindEvent(opts.ele, 'click');` you were close!

First, you need to figure out what the function `bindEvent()` does.

```js
F.bindEvent = function(ele, eventName) {
   var self = this;
   $(document).on(eventName, ele, function(e) {
      self.filterTimer(self.opts.timeout || 35);
   });
};
```

It is requiring two parameters: **Element** and **event name**

So this is how you should pass the element to that function:

```js
this.bindEvent($('#searchbtn').ele, 'click');
```

Now, when you click on that button, the form will be submitted, and you probably don't want that. So either you have to remove your `<form>` tag or simply add `e.preventDefault();` to your `F.bindEvent` function.

See the updated code on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jmgc3y6w/).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this https://jsfiddle.net/86ae9bkn/

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<h3>Search</h3>

<input type="text" id="search-box" placeholder="Type here &hellip;" />

<button id="search-btn">Search</button>

<ul id="results"></ul>

<script>

    $("#search-btn").click(function () {

        let matches = []

        let input = $("#search-box").val()

        let list = document.getElementById("results")
        
        let data =
            [
                { title: "Robert Tester" },
                { title: "John Citizen" },
                { title: "Paul Persons" }
            ]

        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

            let str = Object.values(data[i]).join().toLowerCase()

            if (str.includes(input.toLowerCase())) {
                matches.push(data[i])
            }
        }

        list.innerHTML = matches.map(i => `<li>${i.title}</li>`).join("")
    })

</script>
```